# SSRS FormatNumber Error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

trying to format number (decimal), but it shows me `#Error` on production server:

```
=FormatNumber(First(Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value, "document"), 0)
```

but on developers server it works fine.
Maybe someone know, how can i resolve this?

p.s. without formatting it works on production server fine too.

Comment: What about `=Format(First(Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value, "document"), "N0")`? Or just applying `N0` in the textbox `Format` property and not trying to apply the formatting with an expression? I would try removing the formatting from the expression and setting the textbox property first, if that's acceptable.

Comment: @IanPreston: if i set Custom Format `N0` i get `1434450.000`, so it not work.
if i use expression - i get `N0`... its strange....

Comment: The reason for the error is that SSRS is not recognising the field as a numeric type for some reason... So try something like: `=FormatNumber(CDec(First(Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value, "document")), 0)` which should either solve the issue or prove that SSRS can't do the numeric conversion for some reason. As to why it can't convert, it's difficult to say without access to your data.

Comment: @IanPreston: i tried this before - `#Error`...

Comment: Maybe the localisation is different between servers, so the expected numeric formats are different? Another thing to consider is applying an explicit cast to `decimal` at the database level if you're currently returning a string for that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @IanPreston says, it is most likely a type conversion error. I imagine your production data has some invalid characters for that column or some `Null` columns that make the numeric conversion fail.

You can use the `Val` function to do the conversion. `Val` differs from other numeric conversion functions in that it won't error when the string to be converted isn't numeric - it just does the best job it can.

So try an expression like this for the `Value` property:

```
=IIF(Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value Is Nothing, 
  Nothing, 
  IIF(IsNumeric(Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value), 
    Val(Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value), 
    Fields!SumWithMailDelivery.Value)
)
```

then use `N0` as the `Format` property to format it as numeric if possible.

This formula will:

- Leave the cell as `Nothing` if the field is `Null`
- Convert to numeric and use the appropriate format if possible
- Otherwise just output whatever is in the field